# Does physical stress on vagaus nerve cause depression?

Tags: depression, nerves, heart, psychologist-psychology, nervous-system

I usually suffer from palpitations due to stimulation of vagus nerve from gastric problems and sitting/lying posture.

Recently I've been experiencing some abnormal mental stress patterns such as slow onset of mental depression leading to defeaning negative thoughts and then these symptoms suddenly vanish and leaving me wondering "what just happened?"

Recently I've started to notice that these depression episodes occur along with a  uncomfortable feeling on the left chest region from center to lower left as if a nerve string is upset.

I know I should seek the help of a professional for this but for my own curiosity I wonder if this mental stress can be caused by an upset vagus nerve

Answer (score -1):

Surely all interconnected, however, mental stress by definition is caused by signals from outside and on your psychics, so the answer logically is No, but if you define pain and any nerve disorder by itself a mental stress, than answer is definitely Yes. You should focus on What To Do Approach and find doctors who are competent to relieve your pains without harming you mentally and physically.

Comment: Well not exactly pain. More like something promoting negative mindset out of the blue making clear thoughts hard